# Drupal 6 Module Code Change Not Updating

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

At my current place of employment I've inherited a Drupal 6 site that I am maintaining and updating. There's a custom module that has some copy in it that needs to be updated.

Naturally, I went in and edited the .module file in my local environment, tested it and it looked great. We pushed the file to our development server and cleared the caches, theme registry etc and the change will not take place. It is still reading as the old copy.

As I've said, I've cleared the cache, deactivated/reactivated the module etc.. I've even tried to run update.php but the module in question doesn't actually appear in that list (there's no hook_update in this module it would seem). Is there some other trick to getting Drupal modules to register a change in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that the PHP process is not reading the new file but has the old one cached. You should restart your php-fpm or apache, depending which way you are running the site, to make sure the APC or Opcache are cleared as well.

I would also double check the content of the actual .module file to be extra certain that the new version is really there.

Yet another possibility that comes to mind is that you'll have to make sure you are updating the code in the correct location, ie you need to double check that the web server is serving Drupal from the location you are updating.

Comment: The weird thing is we removed the module folder altogether and its still showing in the module listing too. So I guess that means what? It's being served from somewhere else? We don't see these files anywhere else on the server.

Comment: That, or the APC/Opcache being really stubborn. Have you tried restarting php-fpm and/or your web server? There may of course be other cache layers at play too, if you are into that kind of thing (think nginx microcache or Varnish or similar).

Comment: We restarted the server twice. Still no go =(. Also checked the file to make sure changes were in it and they were. Maddening!

Comment: Next steps perhaps: check if changes elsewhere in the installation are visible on the web. Also check for the use of any external caches (where does the dns point to?)

Comment: Good point, I should mention that CSS changes and .tpl changes do show up.

Comment: In that case. There is (at least) one more thing to try. Run `find [path to installation] -type f -name [module name].module` and see if it finds more than one result.

Comment: This ended up being the case:

"Yet another possibility that comes to mind is that you'll have to make sure you are updating the code in the correct location, ie you need to double check that the web server is serving Drupal from the location you are updating."

There was another directory where the modules were being pulled in from.